# Parse empty tag

Tags: java, android, xml, xmlpullparser

XmlPullParser does not parse self-closing tag, simply skip it, even "isEmptyElementTag" doesn't help. How to solve this problem? 
I want to parse self-closing tag company.

XML structure

```
<phone>
    <id>1</id>
    <company/> // it should parse
    <model>Galaxy</model>
    <price>18000</price>
</phone>
```

Code:

```
    try {
        XmlPullParser xpp = prepareXpp();
        while (xpp.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {

            switch (xpp.getEventType()) {

                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:

                    if (xpp.isEmptyElementTag()) {
                        tagName = "company"; }

                      break;

                case XmlPullParser.TEXT:

                    if (tagName.equals("company")) {
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Empty tag"  );
                    }

                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            xpp.next();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  XmlPullParser prepareXpp () {
    return getResources().getXml(R.xml.data);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in documentation:

> Empty element (such as <tag/>) will be reported with two separate
>   events: START_TAG, END_TAG

So it does not enter `case XmlPullParser.TEXT:` tag.

If you add some logging to `START_TAG` you should see logs in console:

```
case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
    if (xpp.isEmptyElementTag()) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Empty tag"); 
    }
    break;
```

**Edit:** You could try to do next workaround move your xml file to raw folder and add next code to :

```
XmlPullParser prepareXpp () {
    InputStream istream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.data);
    XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
    XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
    xpp.setInput(istream, "UTF-8");
    return xpp;
}
```

Comment: @Samur are you sure xml is the same structure as you wrote? Because locally it's working for me.

Comment: I've update my answer. Now it should work. But I guess it's some bug with getResources().getXml(R.xml.data)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this usinf this.
[isWhitespace()](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser#isWhitespace()) function.

When I process TEXT eventType, I evalute that function.

Ang assign *null* to a variable String value.

Be aware that only work on certains event types.

For me it works!
Best Regards